# Change TCP Port:3306 for Google Cloud SQL instance

Tags: google-cloud-sql

How does one change the TCP Port on a Google Cloud SQL instance.

The Google MySQL server is listening on Port:3306. This will not work in my environment; the port number needs to be different.

I do not see how to change this in Developers Console - Cloud Storage.

I do see documentation for [Networking and Firewalls](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking?hl=en#developer-console-external-http), and it seems TCP Port settings are handled with VM Instances. But I don't understand the relationship between the Cloud SQL instance and the VM instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The port on a Cloud SQL instance cannot be changed. There isn't any relationship between Cloud SQL and Google Compute Engine VMs and their firewall configurations.

Comment: "There isn't any relationship between Cloud SQL and Google Compute Engine VMs" I was confusing two services.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to change the port to which the Cloud SQL instance is listening.

Google Cloud SQL is essentially a wrapper for a MySQL server. It exposes all the same features except operating system access and file system access. Configuring the port requires either changing some environment variables as shown in ['Setting Environment Variables'](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/setting-environment-variables.html) or modifying the MySQL configuration files as shown in ['Using Option Files'](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/option-files.html).

If you really need to use a different port, your best bet within the Google Cloud Platform is to use a Compute Engine VM instance and install your own MySQL server on that. You will however, have to manage your own backups, SSL, etc.

A quick look a Google's [public issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/googlecloudsql/issues/list?can=1&q=port&colspec=ID+Type+Status+Priority+Milestone+Owner+Summary+log&cells=tiles) reveals no feature requests filed to add this functionality to the SDK.