# Why does sqlalchemy seem to be spontaneously committing certain queries while ignoring others?

Tags: python, mysql, google-cloud-platform, beautifulsoup, sqlalchemy

I have a quirky GCP cloud function that does, at sort of a high level, unintelligent website scraping, by taking advantage of the website accepting a numerically ascending 'id' parameter.

**main.py**

```py
def upsert(db, i, x, y):
    with db.connect() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(f"REPLACE INTO TABLE_NAME (i, x, y) VALUES (i, \"{x}\", \"{y}\"")

def main(data, context):
    db = sqlalchemy.connect(...)

    for i in range(0, 100):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(f"websiteimscraping.com/id={i}")
        if soup is not valid:
            continue

        x = soup.find_all(...)
        y = soup.find_all(...)

        upsert(db, i, x, y)
```

In this example, I know for a fact that most if not all of the id's 0 thru 99 are valid + unique and I should have a very similar amount of rows in the database when the cloud function is complete.

To verify that I have 100 rows in MySQL, I enter debug mode and evaluate the expression:

```py
list(cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME"))
```

and I get back like 20% of the rows i'd expect, without any semblance of order. with ids Like (7, 8, 9, 10, 13, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 86)

I do some print statements to make sure none of my edge cases are triggered (which would result in skipping an invalid id) and indeed, none are in the code, which I verified by stepping through in debug mode and seeing all the id's sent to the `upsert` step.

Something which I think is important to clarify is that the rows saved to the database each time are not randomly determined -> it's the same rows each time that are not inserted/updated.

A core assumption I'm making is that if there were to be a data issue for the rows that are not being inserted which caused some issue with the `REPLACE` statement, sqlalchemy would raise an exception for me. sqlalchemy raised no exceptions throughout the entire function.

**Is there anything *not* data related with regards to sqlalchemy that could be causing rows not to be inserted?**

I have tried looking for patterns in the data for the rows that have been inserted to try to gauge some sort of data (in)consistency or patterns (which would seem like the likelier suspect) but haven't found any.

I wish it were simpler for me to give the code away for reproducing but I'm pretty sure no one wants to set up their own mysql instance to try this out - if you are, I am happy to give the actual code and you can try it yourself.

Comment: I'd be glad to check out your code if you provide it. If I don't see anything strange I will try to reproduce the whole scenario.

Comment: @Ajordat requirements.txt https://pastebin.com/e3AkmnKB main.py https://pastebin.com/wu5Rupqi

Comment: @Ajordat you'll want to do this as well so you can run everything locally https://stackoverflow.com/a/62056481/8652920

Comment: Where are you committing the changes? Are you calling `db.commit()` or is the session configured to be auto-committing?

Comment: i'm fairly new to the concept of sessions, but I tried using a session and had the same results: `main.py` https://pastebin.com/6MZfgxqu (possible i used it incorrectly though)

Comment: doesn't make a lot of sense why even without committing there would be changes persisted to the database - i had been assuming that sqlalchemy operated executions in a context manager way and did some sort of persisting in `__exit__`, but that's just a guess @DustinIngram

Comment: Does this work as expected when run somewhere other than the Cloud Functions execution environment?

Comment: i initially used `sqlite3` as a database solution which worked perfectly fine - then i switched to google cloud mysql which only involved minor syntactical changes @DustinIngram (i should note that I'm not deploying it to google cloud at this point, only running locally)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have executed your code and I managed to reproduce your scenario, encountering the same problem that only some rows seem to be inserted.

The problem is that you are using a REPLACE statement. As stated in [MySQL's documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replace.html) a REPLACE statement works exactly like an INSERT operation **but** if the `PRIMARY KEY` already exists said row is **replaced** instead of failing the query.

As per your shared code it seems like you are using the field `code` as `PRIMARY KEY` but you are checking the field `id` as an indicator of an inserted web page. What happens is that multiple rows have the same `code`, thus every time one is inserted the previous one is removed.

I have solved your issue simply making the field `id` the `PRIMARY KEY` instead of `code`. Once you change that (remember to drop the original table), you can run your code again and you will see no missing `id`s. You can verify it using:

```
SELECT id FROM CLASSES_MASTER;
```

By the way, now that you have all the data inserted you can check the amount of repeated codes with this:

```
SELECT code, COUNT(*) FROM CLASSES_MASTER GROUP BY code;
```

Comment: so there's no issue with sqlalchemy - the core of the problem was a central misunderstanding of my data set, as i never considered the possibility of my primary key being incorrect

Comment: @notacorn Don't worry, it was one of those _simple_ mistakes that can make anyone go crazy if it's not immediately found. Glad to help!